# List function acting unexpectedly

Tags: python, list, function, recursion

```
def print_list(l):
    for item in l:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            print_list(item)
        else:
            print(item)
```

I have written this function which uses recursion to properly print a list, but my question is when I give it an argument like `[[1, 2, 3], 4]` according to me it should terminate after displaying `3` but it still properly displays all 4 values what is the reason, can someone enlighten me.

Comment: Note that type checking like this is a bad idea, as it will mean it won't work with other iterables, which makes your function less flexible.

Comment: You'll want to take a look at the [`pprint`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html) module.

Answer (score 4):

I think you misunderstand recursion.

The outer list has two items, one a list, and one the number 4. The `print_list()` function calls `print_list()` again to print the inner list, then calls `print(4)` for the second element.

So, this is what happens:

1. `print_list([[1, 2, 3], 4])` -> loop over 2 items

   1. `print_list([1, 2, 3])` -> loop over 3 items

      1. `print(1)`
      2. `print(2)`
      3. `print(3)`
   2. `print(4)`

Answer (score 0):

When I try your function I get

```
1
2
3
4
```

as output. This is exactly what you would expect, because your function first enters recursion, looping over `[1, 2, 3]`. This prints `1` to `3`. Then the recursion finishes, returning to the original invocation, that prints the second element in the outer list, which is `4`.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you expect the program to terminate at three?
You are right if you say the recursion stops with a printout of the number three but the original list is still not fully processed at this moment. If you write down the steps of your program it could read like this:

- Iterate over ALL elements in iterable [[1, 2, 3], 4]
- Is first item [1, 2, 3] a list? -> Yes
- Call print_list with first item

  - Iterate over all items in [1, 2, 3]
  - Is first item 1 a list? -> No
  - print 1
  - Is second item 2 a list? -> No
  - print 2
  - Is third item 3 a list? -> No
  - print 3
  - Reached end of list so go back
- Is second item 4 a list? -> No
- print 4